# Help with prepositions: "possibilities of having", "a continuance for my hearing"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I am writing to seek possibilities **of** having a continuance **for** my hearing on 02/13/2014.

Comment: Use *of* in both places.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is probably grammatical, but it's awkward and the word choice is poor.  What does it mean to "seek possibilities"?  Oh, you'd get the meaning across, no problem, but it sounds odd.

Here's my advice: be bold and assertive.  Do not *seek possibilities*, just come right out and say what you want.  Try this:

"I am writing to request a continuance of my hearing on 2/13/2014." And then indicate the reasons why the continuance should be granted, and suggest a reasonable date for when you would actually be available.

By the way, in a matter of legal procedure you say a "continuance of", not a "continuance for".  A "continuance" in US legalese is a word they use instead of "postponement", so the same preposition, "of" is what is used.

By the way, if you are actually trying to request a continuance in some case, check this out:

http://www.ehow.com/how_2300659_write-request-continuance.html

Comment: Thank you very much. I am so glad to receive advice from a native speaker. It is easy for me to make mistakes when I have to write about a new topic for which I do not have much reading as backup, such as writing a request for a continuance. Thanks you again.